# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (Converting angular to angular 4)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**Console log**

```
 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15192:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:34:35)
    at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.
js:105:20)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:152:50)
    at new AotPlugin (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:27:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:55:
12)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typ
escript.js:71:19)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:2
9:37)
    at Class.run (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:43:98)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (c:\Users\Amina\Desktop\LendingTree\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:114:26
)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

**Package.Json**

```
 {
  "name": "lending-tree",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

- I have created a new project with cli **ng new projectName**
- Replaced app folder with my existing project.
- Added template for front view in the root directory of an application.
- Updated index.html **only added some css and scripts**.
- Moved main.ts **src** to **app** folder, and changed the imports statements.
- That are only changes, I have made so far.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Hello jonrsharpe I created new angular application with angular-cli and view it in the browser it was working fine. When I updated index.html and app folder i have created few files in the app, use some scripts and css in the index.html file application is not visible in the browser.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does '_Cannot Get_' mean? Please edit your question and add all required code and error messages to the question.

Comment: `Cannot Get/` is the default text when the server doesn't find a entry point to display (normally _index.html_). This could be of various reasons, please provide more information of potentional errors on the console and a relevant part of your code.

Comment: @ventiseis I have just updated my question with some code please check this out .

Comment: @cyrix  I have just updated my question with some code please check this out

Comment: @jonrsharpe you dont need to suppose please check the updated question, thanks.

Comment: Please re-read the help article I linked, then *provide a [mcve]*.